# How to debug in visual studio with pdb file when you dont have vsproj and sln files

Tags: windows, debugging, makefile, visual-studio-2008, pdb-files

I work with very old project which was written in visual studio 2008. I have directories with .cpp files, .h files etc.
The problem is that, they deleted vsproj and sln files, and put Makefile which will compile the project.
So i compiled the project using Cygwin, and now i have also PDB file and an EXE file.

Now, i want to add features to that project. And compile it. But i dont know how to debug it!

So my friend told that all i need is a Pdb file. Ok, so i have a pdb file, but what next? I googled and didnt find clear tutorial or explanation how to do this.

I understood that VS2008 need pdb file to debug. But i havnt vsproj, or sln so i cant press F5 to debug.
I tried "attach to process", but didnt help me.

Please! How to debug with pdb when you cant open a "Solution of project"?

Comment: you can add new empty project to VS and in it properties->debugging->command set path to your exe file. set it as startup project and start debugging

Comment: Wow! Thank you very match -RbMm! It works:)

Comment: -RbMm did it work because i have a pdb file?

Comment: really you can debug any exe without pdb. but with pdb you will view internal symbols names (say names of functions). if pdb containing source line information and you have src files - you can debug with src. so debug itself posible and without pdb, but pdb make this process more easy